# How to implement motion sensor in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sensors

I want to perform a action, when the phone shacked(motion sensor),that could be done with in 1-3 seconds of time. do I need to motion sensor or Acceleration. any suggestions, now I'm performing the action with IBAction.

Any idea?

Comment: thanks for this, but How do I keep the time restriction?

Comment: Implement above solution in your app. And see what you need more then  write some condition to achive that.

Comment: How can we check acceleration in simulator?

Comment: You can't check in simulator. You must have device to work with sensors.